# How to interpret TraMineRs results of disstreedisplay and seqtreedisplay?

Tags: r, traminer

I am not quite sure what the differences are between the outputs and results of `disstreedisplay` and `seqtreedisplay`. Maybe you could explain me the differences? 
The [TraMineR users guide](http://mephisto.unige.ch/pub/TraMineR/doc/TraMineR-Users-Guide.pdf) and the otherwise detailed [working paper](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WeightedCluster/vignettes/WeightedCluster.pdf) about the `WeightedCluster` library do not explain so much about that. Here is my example R script:

```
library(TraMineR) 
library(WeightedCluster) 

data(mvad)
mvad.alphabet <- c("employment", "FE", "HE", "joblessness", "school", "training")
mvad.labels <- c("Employment", "Further Education", "Higher Education", "Joblessness", 
"School", "Training")
mvad.scodes <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")
mvadseq <- seqdef(mvad[, 17:86], alphabet = mvad.alphabet, states = mvad.scodes, 
labels = mvad.labels, weights = mvad$weight, xtstep = 6)

mvad.ham <- seqdist(mvadseq, method="HAM")

seqtree <- seqtree(mvadseq ~ gcse5eq + Grammar + funemp, data=mvad, diss=mvad.ham, 
weight.permutation="diss")
seqtreedisplay(seqtree, type="d", border=NA)

disstree <- disstree(mvaddist ~ gcse5eq + Grammar + funemp, data = mvad, R = 10)
disstreedisplay(disstree, imagefunc=seqdplot, imagedata=mvadseq, border=NA, 
withlegend=FALSE, axes=FALSE, ylab="")
```

You need to have installed GraphViz to see the graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequence regression trees and dissimilarity based trees are fully presented in the following paper:

Studer, M., Ritschard, G., Gabadinho, A. & Müller, N.S. (2011), "Discrepancy Analysis of State Sequences", *Sociological Methods and Research*. Vol. 40(3), pp. 471-510.

Basically, `seqtree` and `seqtreedisplay` are shortcuts (helper functions) to `disstree` and `disstreedisplay` functions (specifying some defaults such as the plotting and printing function to use and so on). `disstree` is more general and can be used to analyse any kind of objects described by a distance matrix.

The difference in your output comes from the use of the weights. `seqtree` uses the sequences weights by default (those defined in `seqdef`). If you use `disstree`, you need to specify the weights explicitly to get the same result.

Thus, `disstree` must be:

```
disstree <- disstree(mvad.ham ~ gcse5eq + Grammar + funemp, data=mvad,
weights=mvad$weight, R=10, weight.permutation="diss")
```